# Is this function $f(z) = e^{\overline z}$ entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I'm trying to find if $e^{\overline z}$ is an entire function.Here is what I have done so far:

To show if a function is entire we should show that function $f(z)$ is analtyic for every $z$.

Therefore I assumed $z$ as $z=x+iy$ hence $\overline z =x-iy$. So $ e^{\overline z}= e^{x-iy} $.
I have calculated the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ and found the following:

$f_x=e^{x-iy}$

$f_{xx}=e^{x-iy}$

$f_y=-i e^{x-iy}$

$f_{yy}=-e^{x-iy}$

Then using Laplace equation, $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$. It seems to me that function is analytic and therefore entire for every z.

However solution manual says that it is not analytic for any z. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not analytic $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}f\neq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write: $$e^{\overline z} = e^{x-iy} = e^x\left[\cos y - i\sin y\right] = u +iv$$ where $u = e^x\cos y$ and $v = -e^x\sin y$.

Use the *Cauchy-Riemann equations* to show that the **function is not analytic**.

Note that if $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are harmonic functions in a domain $D$, then $f(z) = u + iv$ need **not be analytic** in $D$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have done the following and found it:

$u=e^{x} cosy$ and $u=- e^{x} siny$ so,

$u_x=e^{x} cosy$ and $u_y=-e^{x} siny$ and also

$v_x=- e^{x} siny$ and $v_y=-e^{x} cosy$. Since $v_y \not= -v_x$ hence it is not analytic and therefore not entire.

Comment: @eldvin No problem.....

Comment: @eldvin Yes, you have calculated correctly. Just take care of the $u$ and $v$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
With $e^{\bar{z}}=e^x\cos y-ie^x\sin y=u+iv$, use **Cauchy-Riemann** equations and find analyticity region.

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you know that the exponential function is entire. If Your function was enteire, then their product would be entire too. But their product is $z\mapsto e^{2\operatorname{Re}z}$, which is a non-constant function from $\mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb R$. I guess that you know how to prove (using the Cauchy-Riemann equations) that no such entire function exists.